# Creating click event of the buttons that are generated dynamically in angular flx-ui-datatable, in the actionButtons part

Tags: angular, web

I just want to handle a click event to a button that i generated in the flx-ui-datatable.

The code for generating that button is:

```
<flx-ui-datatable
      [headers]="['Klienti','Personi Kontaktues','Qyteti','Telefoni Mobil','Email']"
      [dataKeys]="['client','contactperson','city','mobile','email']"
      dataUrl="http://localhost/blabla" 
      [hasActionButtons]="true"
      [actionButtons]="buttons"
></flx-ui-datatable>
```

, the buttons array conatins:

```
buttons = [
{class:'btn-primary', icon:'fa fa-edit',tooltip:'Edit',tooltipPosition:'top'},
{class:'btn-danger', icon:'fa fa-trash',tooltip:'Delete',tooltipPosition:'top'}
```

];

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flx-ui-datatable), you will find its quite simple. There are 5 events and each is handling a particular event and details are in the docs.

```
firstActionButtonClicked()
secondActionButtonClicked()
thirdActionButtonClicked()
mutipleSelectionClicked()
addButtonClicked
```

Most likely `addButtonClicked` is what you are looking for. Just add it in along the tag and sign your function to it.